# Error in installing sip4.16.3 for PyQt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, ubuntu-14.04, python-sip

I am trying to install PyQt4 on mu ubuntu 14.o4 LTS.
The installation manual says that before installing PyQt, sip must be installed having version atleast 4.16 .
So, I downloaded the archive and installed it as given [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/sip4/installation.html)

```
python configure.py
```

However, when I type sip -V to know the version of sip, I get 4.15. Also if at this stage I try to install PyQt, the installation aborts saying that sip version atleast 4.16 is required
So, I tried to uninstall previously installed sip by `pip uninstall sip`.
This threw an error, I am pasting the contents of pip.log here.

```
------------------------------------------------------------
/usr/bin/pip run on Thu Oct  9 06:48:46 2014
Cannot uninstall requirement sip, not installed
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/uninstall.py", line 59, in run
    requirement_set.uninstall(auto_confirm=options.yes)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 1035, in uninstall
    req.uninstall(auto_confirm=auto_confirm)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req.py", line 505, in uninstall
    raise UninstallationError("Cannot uninstall requirement %s, not installed" % (self.name,))
UninstallationError: Cannot uninstall requirement sip, not installed
```

It clearly says that sip is not installed on the system. I am confused about what is happening over here. Please help.

**EDIT**
Also please note that `import sip` from within python confirms that no module named sip is there.

Comment: You can [download the source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/sip/sip-4.16.3/sip-4.16.3.tar.gz), extract it and then install it.

Comment: I was doing the same.